# included php cannot access form on the page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have some html code used in more than one place, I put it in a .php file and include it where needed.  In one case I include this code inside a form.

This form has one element; and just below that, inside the form, is the include for the php file that has the html code.

I find that the included html from the .php file cannot access the form element but the one element that is on the same page as the form has no such trouble.

Here's the included code that's in a separate .PHP file:

```
 // inside theIncluded.php
 <div id="aDivToBeIncluded">Testing</div>
```

And here is my form declaration -- the signature looks overly complex because I removed other elements (text boxes, etc) for this explanation:

```
    <form style="display: inline-block" name="areaComboboxForm" method="post" 
        autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <select name="mySelect" id="mySelectId"  onchange="return doChange(this)" >
        <option value="one">one</option>         
        <option value="two">two</option>  
        <option value="three">three</option>    
       </select>

       <?php require_once("theIncluded.php") ?>

     </form>
```

And here is the troublesome code:

```
 function doChange(theSelect)
 { 
     var theSelect = document.getElementById('mySelectId');

      // THIS REPORTS THAT THE FORM IS 'objectHTMLFormElement' 
     alert("doChange(), the form is: " + theSelect.form);


    var theIncludedDiv= document.getElementById('aDivToBeIncluded');

      // THIS REPORTS THAT theIncludedDiv IS  'objectHTMLDivElement'
    alert("doChange(), the included Div is: " + theIncludedDiv);

      // THIS REPORTS THAT theIncludedDiv.form IS 'undefined'
    alert("doChange(), the form is: " + theIncludedDiv.form);
 }
```

To recap, I include some html code from a .php file that has one DOM element, a div.
That div, when accessed on the page where its .php file is included, resolves to an
objectHTMLDivElement.

But when I try to access the .form that the objectHTMLDivElement is included on -- the form is 'undefined.'

Is there a reason for this?  All this code is in the same folder on the same webserver, a localhost XAMPP web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, the div is inside the form and has no .form of its own.

You'd be looking for `theIncludedDiv.parentNode` if you wanted the form element.

`.form` is only a property of [HTMLInputElements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/HTMLInputElement#Properties) in HTML4 and in HTML5 it has some different behavior(it can be the `id` of the form element or null).

Comment: I'm not familiar with `.form` but I was going to ask, does an element have to be a form element for `.form` to work?

Comment: @AndrewPK  I viewed the page source. The included div is on the form and one line below the select.  My take is that the server serves up the page like this and as far as the browser knows, the div was put there, hard-coded in the page html, just like the select above it.  There's no difference as far as the 'view source' between the select and the div, both of which are inside the form and /form tags.  The browser has no way of knowing that the div was included on the page by way of a php include.

Comment: My initial answer is wrong. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FHTMLInputElement#Properties

I'll update asap

Comment: @AndrewPK  100% confirmed.  I accessed the div.parentNode and sure enough, it is of type objectHTMLFormElement.  I also hard-coded a div on the form itself -- not one included from a php file, but hard-coded right on the same page as the form declaration -- and checked its form value -- and it too is undefined.  Cleared up that mystery for me -- thanks.